Carousel with adaptive text position over image with fixed width
There is carousel with text over image 1200px wide.
Overlapping of elements is achieved using grid areas, instead of position relative/absolute. The carousel is working with scroll-snap module.
UPDATE:
The goal is moving the text to the left when width is decreased:

Now the text is cut off instead of moving responsively:

Breakpoint(max-width: 981px) in source is just for full example. The issue occurs before that breakpoint(width=1120px on pictures above)


.carousel {
  display: grid;
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  grid-template-areas: 'item-1 item-2 item-3';
}

.carousel .item {
  display: grid;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}

.carousel .item-1 {
  grid-area: item-1;
  grid-template-areas: 'first';
}

.carousel .item-2 {
  grid-area: item-2;
  grid-template-areas: 'second';
}

.carousel .item-3 {
  grid-area: item-3;
  grid-template-areas: 'third';
}

.carousel .item-1 .image {
  grid-area: first;
}

.carousel .item-2 .image {
  grid-area: second;
}

.carousel .item-3 .image {
  grid-area: third;
}

.carousel .item-1 .text {
  grid-area: first;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
}

.carousel .item-2 .text {
  grid-area: second;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
}

.carousel .item-3 .text {
  grid-area: third;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: end;
}
<section class="carousel">

  <div class="item item-1">
    <picture class="image">
      <source srcset="https://placehold.co/800x732" media="(max-width: 981px)" width="800" height="732" />
      <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x732" alt="" width="1200" height="732" />
    </picture>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-2">
    <picture class="image">
      <source srcset="https://placehold.co/800x732" media="(max-width: 981px)" width="800" height="732" />
      <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x732" alt="" width="1200" height="732" />
    </picture>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item item-3">
    <picture class="image">
      <source srcset="https://placehold.co/800x732" media="(max-width: 981px)" width="800" height="732" />
      <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x732" alt="" width="1200" height="732" />
    </picture>
    <div class="text">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </div>
  </div>

</section>




Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Your problem is unclear, "but this does not work" - what does not work? And what is the expected behavior?

The picture element maintains a width of 1200px even when an image with dimensions 800x732 is loaded. This happens because the width of img is set to 1200px, and the source element only updates the src attribute without adjusting the size.
To fix the issue, you'll need to replace the HTML code with the following:
    <picture class="image">
      <source srcset="https://placehold.co/800x732" media="(max-width: 981px)" width="800" height="732" />
      <img src="https://placehold.co/1200x732" alt="" width="1200" height="732" />
    </picture>


Breakpoint is not case of issue, please, see updated question above. But I added width/height to source.

The issue is solved by using several breakpoints with margin-right for .text element
